# initializing my factory through spring

Tags: java, spring, initialization, factory

Can I have a factory as follows?

```
public class Factory
{
    private static Map<EnumXyz, IDAO> map = new HashMap<Sting, Object>();


    public static void init()
    {
        //how do i initialize my map through spring initialization
    }

    public static IDAO getDAO(EnumXyz dao)
    {
        if (map.containsKey(dao))
        return map.get(dao);
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("dao not supported " + dao);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

1. How do I take care of the initialization of my factory through spring?
2. Is this way of building a factory correct?
3. Any other, better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would instantiate your factory as a bean itself, and have an *instance* of it - don't make everything static. Spring itself can control whether your bean is a singleton (it will default as such).

e.g.

```
public class Factory {
   public Factory(final Map<String,Object} map) {
      this.map = map;
   }
}
```

and your Spring config:

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="Factory">
   <constructor-arg>
      <util:map>
        <!-- configure your map here, or reference it as a separate bean -->
        <entry key="java.lang.String" value="key">....</entry>
      </util:map>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In your constructor, pass in the map which is defined itself in your Spring config.

Comment: did not get you, can u elaborate

Comment: and Factory itself will be singleton class?

Comment: Factory can be called from multiple places, so how can i make sure that there is only one instance of factory?

Comment: If you want it to be a singleton. There will be one instance of it per application context (you'll likely only have one application context). The above instantiates an instance of the Factory class and gives it the map upon construction

Comment: I understood ur code.But my question if i make it singleton then how can i initialize it? should i have a public method init that takes map as argument?

Comment: can we have a chat on stackoverflow?

Comment: Regrettably I don't have chat access here. The Spring framework will instantiate that bean (you'll probably configure using the config and FileSystemXmlApplicationContext or similar) and then you just call getBean("myFactory") to get that bean with the configured map

Comment: @user978939 you just have to redefine the word "singleton". It's not a singleton in the sense that only one instance can exist per classloader, but rather Spring will manage it and ensure that there is only one instance per application (which may have multiple classloaders)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd : If my class A,B both of which wants to use the factory how can i make sure that they dont create new instances of factory? Cant i  have something like Factory.getInstance()?can we have a chat here?

Comment: @user978939 chat here: no, but you can skype me (my contact page)

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't make everything static, especially not the init() method.
2. Annotate your bean with `@Component`
3. Annotate your `init()` method with `@PostConstruct`.

Now the `init()` method is called when Spring constructs your Factory class, providing it a hook to initialize itself.